# Changing a map image into nodes and edges

Tags: java, image-processing, graph, edge-detection

I'm developing an application and I have a map like the following and I want to extract the nodes and edges connecting these nodes in order to be able to apply any shortest path algorithm and have the data as a graph. 
I used canny edge detector and it worked however it only displays the image after modification but doesn't save the data and I wanted it as vectors
What can I use to do do the following ???
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyOut.png)

Comment: what results do you have? "it only displays the image after modification but doesn't save the data and I wanted it as vectors": this is inconceivable

Comment: The data which is resulted is an array of pixels. I want to have it as vectors to be able to have a graph representing this map .

Comment: I understand you want all these companies as nodes - then what do you have so far as the result? show images and code

Comment: What you are asking looks like a difficult task tha includes edge detection followed by vectorization, then intelligent graph analysis to recognize the arrows and blocks. You are a long way from the solution.